# Regex extract all numbers specific lenght starting from last

Tags: php, regex

For example i have numbers text

```
8.40083897*
S903040058061*
51097653
1.51097653P
0051384034*51384034* 40083897* 40078422**
```

I need get from this

```
40083897*
40058061*
51097653
51097653
51384034*
40078422**
```

So i use regex

> /([0-9*]{8,10})/

It work good except it takes and count numbers from left, how say to regex count from right?

```
So if exist * then start counting from asteriks and length only 9
So if exist ** then start counting from last asteriks and length only 10
So if not exist * then start counting from last digit and length only 8
```

Comment: Judging by your explicit rules, you need `\d{10}\b(?!\*)|\d{9}\*(?!\*)|\d{8}\*{2}(?!\*)` or `\d{10}\b(?!\*)|\d{8}(?:\d\*)?\*(?!\*)`, but it does not match the expected output.

Comment: i dont coping duplicates

Comment: this one seam to work `\d{8}\b(?!\*)|\d{8}(?:\d\*)?\*(?!\*)|\d{8}\*{2}(?!\*)`

Comment: You could match 8 digits followed by a word boundary and optional asterixes `\d{8}\b\**` https://regex101.com/r/eILpgK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\d{8}(?!\d)\*{0,2}(?!\*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DN1nbi/2).

**Details**

- `\d{8}` - any eight digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit on the right is allowed
- `\*{0,2}` - zero, one or two asterisks
- `(?!\*)`  - not followed with another asterisk.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8LloK):

```php
$s = "8.40083897*\nS903040058061*\n51097653\n1.51097653P\n0051384034*51384034* 40083897* 40078422**\n1.51097653P";
if (preg_match_all('~\d{8}(?!\d)\*{0,2}(?!\*)~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_unique($matches[0]));
}
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 40083897*
    [1] => 40058061*
    [2] => 51097653
    [4] => 51384034*
    [7] => 40078422**
)
```

Comment: but it not extract only numbers without asteriks,  for example 1.51097653P  i need get 51097653

Comment: @SeniorPomidor It does extract numbers without asterisks. `{0,2}` means **zero to two**.

Comment: It not `$s = "1.51097653P";
if (preg_match_all('~\d{8}\b\*{0,2}(?!\*)~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_unique($matches[0]));
}`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I replaced `\b` with `(?!\d)`.